# Validate form with jQuery on submit

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have this function when I click on my submit button:

```
$('#signup-button').click(function(event){
            var username_check = validateUsernameField();
            var email_check = validateEmailField();
            var name_check = validateNameField();
            var birthdate_check = validateBirthdateField();
            event.preventDefault();
            if(username_check && email_check && name_check && birthdate_check) {
                alert('lol');
                var formData = $('#FonykerAddForm').serialize();
                $.ajax ({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?php echo $html->url('/fonykers/add',true); ?>',
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        $( "#confirm-dialog" ).html(response.msg).dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            modal: true,
                            height: 140,
                            title: response.title
                        });       
                        $('#confirm-dialog').dialog('open');
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        alert('Cualquier vaina');
                        alert(xhr.statusText);
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I previously call the validate methods on blur events on my fields, and they all work and the validation here seems to work, the problem is that after the if statement nothing happens, the form isn't submitted. Anybody have any idea why? And if not can you think of a better way to validate all my fields before submit?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in in Firebug and stepping through line-by-line.  Also, you can try running on your forms 'submit' event, e.g. $('form.my_form').submit(function() {
       if ($(this).find('input.my_input').val().length > 20) {
         return false; //return false to prevent submission of form
       }

       return true; //submit form
     });

Comment: have you checked that you `if` is ever `true`?

Comment: define a matching `else{alert("!lol");}` see if that is displayed

Comment: Ok it entered the else, which is weird, because all the fields are marked as valid (they turn green when they're ok)

Comment: Running in firebug I see that they all stay marked as undefined except the birthdate_check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the variables I use in the if statement some were returning undefined so it screwed up the call. I simply replaced checking for the variables to checking for set classes on my DOM elements to see if they have errors and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is `event.preventDefault()`,

If you consider that it is preventing the default action of the submit form it will not work, therefore, a better alternative would be to use `return false;` within each function you are calling.

e.g.

```
function validateUsernameField(){

     if($("#UsernameField").val()=="") {
        // your username actions
        return false;
     }
     else
     {
     username_check = 1  
     return true;
     }
}

if(username_check == 1 && email_check == 1 && name_check == 1 && birthdate_check == 1) {
    alert('lol');

    var formData = $('#FonykerAddForm').serialize();
    $.ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            $( "#confirm-dialog" ).html(response.msg).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 140,
                title: response.title
            });       
            $('#confirm-dialog').dialog('open');

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert('Cualquier vaina');
            alert(xhr.statusText);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });

}else{
    alert ('There is something wrong');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If I don't prevent the default it will do the default POST action and will not execute the AJAX call.